# TikZ path labels and --cycle

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

```
\draw (0,0) -- node{a} (2,0) -- node{b}  (2,1)  -- node{c}  (0,1)  -- cycle;
```

I can't find a simple way to make a label on the last edge. What I want is something like

```
\draw (0,0) -- node{a} (2,0) -- node{b}  (2,1)  -- node{c}  (0,1)  -- node{d} cycle;
```

but it doesn't work.

```
\draw (0,0) coordinate(A) -- node{a} (2,0) -- node{b}  (2,1)  -- 
                             node{c}  (0,1) coordinate(D) -- cycle;
\draw (A) -- node{d} (D);
```

This works, but seems too complicated for such a simple task and I think I'm missing something.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I would probably use `\draw (0,0) -- node{a} (2,0) -- node{b}  (2,1)  -- node{c}  (0,1)  --  node  {d} (0,0) -- cycle ;` (so repeating the first coordinate at the end of the path, and using `cycle` only to get the final corner right).

Comment: This method is much neater than mine, thank you. Still not as elegant as I hoped though...

Comment: But isn't there a way to treat the last `--` as an edge and label it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `cycle` option short circuits the system for putting nodes on paths.  The usual path operations have a system whereby they record their path component so that TikZ can figure out where to put nodes afterwards.  The `--` (lineto) component is no exception to this.  The problem is that the `cycle` interrupts the lineto before it can record the necessary information.

A fix would be to put this information back in.  I don't know how robust this fix is, but it works for your example.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97602/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@@close cycle{%
  \edef\tikz@timer@start{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}
  \tikz@flush@moveto%
  \tikz@path@close{\expandafter\pgfpoint\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto}%
  \edef\tikz@timer@end{\noexpand\pgfpoint\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto}%
  \def\pgfstrokehook{}%
  \let\tikz@timer=\tikz@timer@line%
  \tikz@scan@next@command%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- node{a} (2,0) -- node{b}  (2,1)  -- node[pos=.3]{c}  (0,1)  -- node[pos=.3]{d} cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: closed path with labels]