# Defining a "to path" function that accepts "cycle" as target?

Tags: tikz-pgf

As you probably (don't) know, the idea under `circuitikz` is to use the `to path` facility of Ti*k*Z. Now, I have recently [simplified the function so that it seems to work more or less well](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/417), but I am not able to make it work for closing paths.

I have prepared a very simple MWE --- I define a component shape that is a simple red segment, and I have copied a bare-bone path construction. As you can see in the example below, the stock `to[]` operation works perfectly (as expected) when closing a path with the `cycle` element, while mine fails (sometimes it fails with fireworks) when used in a similar way.

Is there a way to fix it *in the `\goforpath` macro*? I would really refrain from changing internal Ti*k*Z functions, as suggested for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101972/38080), for reasons of maintainability (I have a workaround in the package, but it's manual...).

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{sline}{
    \anchor{center}{
        \pgfpointorigin
    }
    \anchor{left}{\pgf@x=-0.2cm\pgf@y=0pt}
    \anchor{right}{\pgf@x=0.2cm\pgf@y=0pt}
    \backgroundpath{
        \pgfscope
        \pgfsetcolor{red}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.2cm}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.2cm}{0pt}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        \endpgfscope
    }
}
\def\goforpaths{
    coordinate(a) at (\tikztostart)
    coordinate(b) at (\tikztotarget)
    \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{a}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{b}{center}}
        \edef\mydirection{\pgfmathresult}%Calculate direction(angle) of path
    }
    node[sline, rotate=\mydirection](N) at ($(\tikztostart)!0.5!(\tikztotarget)$){}
    -- (\tikztostart) -- (N.left) (N.right) -- (\tikztotarget)
}
\tikzset{slineto/.style={/tikz/to path=\goforpaths}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % this does not work https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97602/tikz-path-labels-and-cycle#comment210067_97602
    \draw[ultra thick]  (0,0) to[slineto] (0,1) to[slineto] (1,1) to[slineto] (1,0) to[slineto] (0,0) -- cycle;
    % nor this (worst):
    \draw[ultra thick]  (1.5,0) to[slineto] (1.5,1) to[slineto] (2.5,1) to[slineto] (2.5,0) to[slineto] cycle;
    % this does work
    \draw[ultra thick]  (3,0) to[] (3,1) to[] (4,1) to[] (4,0) to[]  cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### update: this was too simplified.

[@ZhiyuanLck's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552450/38080) is ok for this case, but consider that in general the node is quite complex, and it is not possible to have it just "superpose" the path. Think of a resistor or a generator or whatever.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{szig}{
    \anchor{center}{
        \pgfpointorigin
    }
    \anchor{left}{\pgf@x=-0.2cm\pgf@y=0pt}
    \anchor{right}{\pgf@x=0.2cm\pgf@y=0pt}
    \backgroundpath{
        \pgfscope
        \pgfsetcolor{red}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.2cm}{-0.0cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.1cm}{-0.1cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.1cm}{0.1cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.2cm}{0.0cm}}
        \pgfsetroundcap
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        \endpgfscope
    }
}
\def\goforpaths{
    coordinate(a) at (\tikztostart)
    coordinate(b) at (\tikztotarget)
    \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{a}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{b}{center}}
        \edef\mydirection{\pgfmathresult}%Calculate direction(angle) of path
    }
    node[szig, rotate=\mydirection](N) at ($(\tikztostart)!0.5!(\tikztotarget)$){}
    -- (\tikztostart) -- (N.left) (N.right) -- (\tikztotarget)
}
\tikzset{slineto/.style={/tikz/to path=\goforpaths}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % this does not work https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97602/tikz-path-labels-and-cycle#comment210067_97602
    \draw[ultra thick]  (0,0) to[slineto] (0,1) to[slineto] (1,1) to[slineto] (1,0) to[slineto] (0,0) -- cycle;
    % nor this (worst):
    \draw[ultra thick]  (1.5,0) to[slineto] (1.5,1) to[slineto] (2.5,1) to[slineto] (2.5,0) to[slineto] cycle;
    % this does work
    \draw[ultra thick]  (3,0) to[] (3,1) to[] (4,1) to[] (4,0) to[]  cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

and if I superpose the node to the path, the red "resistors" will be crossed-out:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-- cycle` use `\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto` to close the path. `\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto` is usually the first coordinate after `\path`. But there is another case, considering following example:

```
\path (0, 0) -- (1, 0) (1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- cycle;
```

`\pgfsyssoftpath@lastmoveto` is `(0, 0)` at begin, but change to `(1, 0)` after.
I think above code should have the same effect as

```
\path (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
\path (1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- cycle;
```

[image]

So the path `\path (1,0) to[slineto] (0,0) -- cycle;` will expand to

```
\path (1, 0) node[sline, rotate=\mydirection](N) at ($(\tikztostart)!0.5!(\tikztotarget)$){}
-- (1, 0) -- (N.left) (N.right) -- (0, 0) -- cycle;`
```

which equals to

```
\path (1, 0) node[sline, rotate=\mydirection](N) at ($(\tikztostart)!0.5!(\tikztotarget)$){}
-- (1, 0) -- (N.left);
\path (N.right) -- (0, 0) -- cycle;
```

### work around

Just let node cover the path rather than breaking the path.

```
\def\goforpaths{
    coordinate(a) at (\tikztostart)
    coordinate(b) at (\tikztotarget)
    \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{a}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{b}{center}}
        \edef\mydirection{\pgfmathresult}%Calculate direction(angle) of path
    }
    node[sline, rotate=\mydirection](N) at ($(\tikztostart)!0.5!(\tikztotarget)$){}
    -- (\tikztotarget)
}
```

[image]

### Some attemp to new requiment

I did some code hacking under the restrictions: **there are all `to path`, i.e., no `line to (--)` or `edge`**.

**Stated first**: this is the only method I could think of, but **I strongly do not recommend to patch the original tikz code!**

Idea is simple, since there actually does not exists the sytax like `to cycle` or `edge cycle`, I add a parsable keyword `mycycle` to be parsed after `to`. When first `to` is parsed, I save the start point (say `a`) and initial direction (say `ang1`). In every `to` operation, inverse direction (say `ang2`) is also saved. So when `mycycle` is parsed at last, lines are manual complete by `(a) ++(ang1:0.1pt) -- (a) -- (ang2:0.1pt)`.

As you see, it is very limited. If you want `mycycle` to be behave as the same as `cycle`, you have to **hack more command**, which is a **big work** and may **destroy the original code structure**

Here is the code and the output:
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newbool{toclose@first@to}
\xpretocmd{\tikz@@command@path}{
  \global\booltrue{toclose@first@to}
}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\tikz@finish}{
  \global\boolfalse{toclose@first@to}
}{}{}
% -- mycycle
% \xpatchcmd{\tikz@lineto@mid}{%
% \tikz@scan@one@point{\tikz@@lineto}%
% }{%
%   \pgfutil@ifnextchar m{\tikz@myclose}{%
%     \tikz@scan@one@point{\tikz@@lineto}%
%   }%
% }{}{}
% to/edge mycycle
\xpatchcmd{\tikz@@to@collect}{%
\tikzerror{(, +, coordinate, pic, or node expected}%)
\tikz@@to@or@edge@coordinate()%
}{
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar m{
    \tikz@myclose
  }{
    \tikzerror{(, +, coordinate, pic, or node expected}%)
    \tikz@@to@or@edge@coordinate()
  }
}{}{}
\def\tikz@myclose mycycle{
  \tikz@scan@next@command
  \tikz@@myclose
}
\def\tikz@@myclose{
  \pgfextra{\typeout{iii \toclose@first@direction}}
  to[\toclose@style](\toclose@first@moveto)
  (\toclose@first@moveto) ++(\toclose@last@direction:0.1pt) --
  (\toclose@first@moveto) -- ++(\toclose@first@direction:0.1pt)
}
% \def\tikz@myclose ycycle{\tikz@scan@next@command}
\pgfdeclareshape{szig}{
  \anchor{center}{
    \pgfpointorigin
  }
  \anchor{left}{\pgf@x=-0.2cm\pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{right}{\pgf@x=0.2cm\pgf@y=0pt}
  \backgroundpath{
    \pgfscope
    \pgfsetcolor{red}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.2cm}{-0.0cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.1cm}{-0.1cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.1cm}{0.1cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.2cm}{0.0cm}}
    \pgfsetroundcap
    \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
  }
}
\def\goforpaths{
  coordinate(a) at (\tikztostart)
  coordinate(b) at (\tikztotarget)
  \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{a}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{b}{center}}
    \edef\mydirection{\pgfmathresult}%Calculate direction(angle) of path
    % save start point and start direction
    \ifbool{toclose@first@to}{
      \xdef\toclose@first@moveto{\tikztostart}
      \xdef\toclose@first@direction{\mydirection}
      \global\booltrue{toclose@first@to}
    }{}
    \pgfmathparse{\mydirection+180}
    \xdef\toclose@last@direction{\pgfmathresult}
  }
  node[szig, rotate=\mydirection](N) at ($(\tikztostart)!0.5!(\tikztotarget)$){}
  -- (\tikztostart) -- (N.left) (N.right) -- (\tikztotarget)
}
% \tikzset{slineto/.style={/tikz/to path=\goforpaths}}
\def\toset#1#2{%
  \gdef\toclose@style{#1}
  \tikzset{#1/.style={to path={#2}}}
}
\toset{slineto}{\goforpaths}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[ultra thick]  (0,0) to[slineto] (0,1) to[slineto] (1,1) to[slineto] (1,0) to[slineto] mycycle;
  \scoped[xshift=3cm] \draw[ultra thick]  (0,0) to[slineto] (1,1) to[slineto] (2,0) to[slineto] mycycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, this is a solution, but if the node is, for example, a zig-zag resistor, then the path will show, and I'll "see¨ the path through it.... I have to explain better, I think. +1 anyway for the information.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no good way to handle `to path` with `cycle`, because `cycle` depends on not only the `lastmoveto` of the path, but also previous path, while `to path` is only part of the whole path.